# jquery incorrect link selection from links table

Tags: php, jquery

Please let me describe the issue.

There is a table of 5 cols and 20+ rows. First column contains a product name that is required later in PHP procedure.
There is a link with coded product name (created from PHP script), different for each row.

There is a jquery dialog confirmation box with two buttons - OK and Cancel. This dialog box comes up after clicking the link in last column.
It is expected that after clicking OK button, PHP script is loaded with _GET method that receives product name from the link.

Actually it works in this way, with one tiny exception - jquery passes always a link from the first row of the table.

Is there a way to detect which link is clicked or maybe is the a way to send a link with a product name taken from the first column?

Please find attached part of the code.

```
        echo "<a href='usunProdukt.php?name=".$T_nazwa."' class='confirmation'><img src='pictures/cross16.jpg' width='10' height='10' /></a>" ;

        echo "</td>" ;
        echo "</tr>";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>


<div id="dialog-message" title="Usuwanie produktu">
        <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-help" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>Czy chcesz usunąć wybrany produkt?
        </p>
        <p>
        Naciśnij OK aby kontynuować.
        </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#dialog-message").hide();
        $('.confirmation').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                        Ok: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        window.location.href = $('.confirmation').attr('href');
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                }
        });
});

</script>
```

Thanks in advance for helping... :)

Answer (score 0):

In your click event you need to get the url from clicked link and then redirect to the correct path:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#dialog-message").hide();
    $('.confirmation').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    window.location.href = lnk;
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Indeed, you are right. It works fine now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me:

```
window.location.href = lnk;
```

Thanks spirit for your help.